# Cannot connect to svn server (svnserve)

Tags: macos, svn

I've set up using many tutorials from the web a repository and svnserve on my mac.

But I cannot access it from the internet.

If I call the following command everything works alright:

```
svn co svn://192.168.1.10 /working_copy/myproject --username me
```

And If I call the following:

```
svn co svn://my_external_ip /working_copy/myproject --username me
```

I get a error: Can't connect to host 'my_external_ip': Connection refused

Of course instead of my_external_ip I type in my external ip address that I got from whatismyip.com

I've set up port forwarding on my router for port 3690 to my local ip - 192.168.1.10

svnserve is running. I launched it with:

```
svnserve -d
```

I tried to check if port 3690 is open using http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and it says that the port is open.

What may be the problem? I'm trying to figure it out for the whole day and can't find the cause.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a networking question, not a programming question.

Comment: Are you 100% sure SVN is listening on port 3690? Can you check using `netstat` when you connect locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where are you when you try the "svn co svn://my_external_ip" command? Chances are that won't work when you're still on your own LAN - cheap NAT routers typically do not forward traffic directed at the public IP coming from the LAN. While you're on your own LAN, you'll need to use the internal IP.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you very much, it's finally working!
Many thanks!